# Importing Java package into aidl android

Tags: android, smack

I want to import java packages in android aidl's. Like org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Stanza in android aidl for implementing it in classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Stanza`](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/4.1.5/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/packet/Stanza.html) is not `Parcelable`, nor does it appear to be `Serializable`, and so it cannot be passed around via AIDL-defined methods.

For Java classes that are either `Parcelable` or `Serializable`, you can add `import` statements to your AIDL, then reference them as normal.